# Button isn't doing anything at all

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm trying to learn swift and button won't do anything that I'm using at the moment.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var ilmaTeade: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tekstiVali: UITextField!
    @IBAction func nupp(sender: AnyObject) {
        var urlString = "http://http://ilm.ee/"+tekstiVali.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
            (data, response, error) in
            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var contentArray = urlContent?.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"current")
            println(contentArray)
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        tekstiVali.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do the little weather app with uDemy course without a API or something(its not really good solution, but im still learning)

Comment: Are you certain that your IBAction is connected to your UIButton in your Storyboard?

Comment: Yup, control-dragged it from there to viewcontroller :)(i tried it to delete action and drag it again but nothing would happen)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
resume
```

On your task object otherwise it won't ever start

Comment: Where do i call it? I have been programming in swift for 2 months and haven't run into problem like this.

Comment: Thanks! Button started to output some data to console, now i gotta fix my code, but that resume method did some wonders! :)

Comment: Oh and.. is it necessary to call resume all the time when working with NSURL-s?

Comment: With NSURLSessionDataTask, yes.

Comment: Thank you chedabob, i would rep you if i had enough points on stackoverflow.. haha, i found huge mistake in my urlString also why i couldn't get data through. :D